# OnDestroy restarts service, how can I destroy my activity without killing or restarting the service?

Tags: android, service, timertask

I'm writting an app that pops up notifications from time to time.
a service is running in the background, and when I kill the app the service is restarted and a notification pops up, but I don't want this to happen.

I want the service to stay there quiet and be executed at the right time.(I'm using a TimerTask)

I don't want to kill or restart the service, I want it to stay there quiet.

Comment: Show us the Service code

Comment: @madhan kumar : I approved your edit. When editing, please also remove things like "Good morning" and "Thanks".

Comment: ok @S.L.Barth here after I'll do.

Answer (score 4):

> when i kill the app the service is restarted and a notification pops up, but i don't want this to happen

In your service's `onStartCommand()` method, return `START_NOT_STICKY`.

(and I *so* wish that this were the default...)

> i want the service to stay there quiet and be executed at the right time.(I'm using a TimerTask)

Use `AlarmManager` to arrange to get executed at the right time; do not use a `TimerTask` in a running service. Only have a service running when it is [actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Watching the clock tick is not actively delivering value to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved after reading the documentation,dozen of stack overflows, and blog posts. I created a background service and made it foreground to prevent it from restarting if the app(process) closed or opened--to prevent the data lose from the service. but again, there was persistent notification produced which was unmovable(I hated it). I wanted to remove this notification along with service started. then started surfing on updating the notification and there I found a question directed me to the documentation of updating notification. I read that and update foreground service notification and vola it worked like charm. I'm giving the complete code here.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    Intent background = new Intent(context,TimeBroadCast.class);
    context.startService(background);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    int message = intent.getIntExtra(UpdatTime.timUpdate,0);
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(message));
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(UpdatTime.ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST)
    );
}


}
```

Service class

```
public class TimeBroadCast extends Service {
private boolean isRunning;
private Context context;
UpdatTime updatTime;
Timer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.context = this;
    this.isRunning = false;
    timer = new Timer();
    updatTime = new UpdatTime(this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    StartForground();
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).build();
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ns);
    nMgr.notify(101,notification);
    nMgr.cancel(101);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    StopForgroudn();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void StartForground() {
    if(!isRunning) {

        isRunning = true;
        timer.schedule(updatTime, 0, 1000);
    }

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.color.transparent)
            .build();
    startForeground(101,  notification);



}

 private  void StopForgroudn()
{
 timer.cancel();  // Terminates this timer, discarding any currently                      scheduled tasks.
timer.purge();   // Removes all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue.
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
  }

}
```

TimerTaks class

```
public class UpdatTime extends TimerTask {

static String timUpdate = "timecountdown", ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST = TimeBroadCast.class.getName() + "TimeBroadCast";
Context myContext;
int i = 0;
public UpdatTime(Context myContext) {
    this.myContext = myContext;
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {



    try {

        i += 1;
        Log.v("Data1", ""+i);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(timUpdate,i);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(myContext).sendBroadcast(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Hops this may helps.
Sorry for the  improper format of the code....